# Attaching a garment to a rigged figure

Tags: rigging

Can't connect the garment to the character's body. I tried DataTransfer according to a video tutorial I saw:
work.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SY17YJHMMMQ.
and this also:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkfgHp_eDdE

Below you can see a screenshot of my work (I downloaded the man). With the DataTransfer data on the side
In the second screenshot I tried to make a Parent between the shirt and the armature. At first it didn't do that to me, just now, but still it does it when I try to do weight paint, like in the second video
[image: Below you can see a screenshot of my work (I downloaded the man). With the DataTransfer data on the side.]
[image: And this is what happened when I tried to make a Parent between the shirt and the armature. At first it didn't do that to me, just now, but still it does it when I try to do weight paint, like in the second video.]

Comment: have you parented the garment to the armature (with the Armature Deform option)?

Comment: A screenshot and one or two sentences about what actually does not work would help to answer this question. Does the garment not move at all or is it badly deformed? Did you check the weights in the vertex groups to make sure they were transferred correctly? A link to the tutorial would also help readers who are interested in your question.

Comment: Hi Yair, welcome to Blender SE. I am sorry, but you didn't give us any really useful informations as you can see in the comments who are just guessing what you did or didn't because you didn't provide that necessary information. So please invest a bit more time in your question, edit it and add detail informations about what you did, add the tutorial link and maybe add your blend file so we can check out it ourselves. Thanks.

Comment: I added details, links and screenshots to the question

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? I added details.

Comment: Thanks for adding the details. The data transfer of the weights requires that the meshes are at the same spot. In your case, it looks like the character and the cloth have different rest positions. In consequence, the cloth doesn't cover the character very well and the transfer will not work for the sleeves. I would create a dummy rig for the cloth (maybe use Rigify's metarig) and align the bones to the cloth. Then bind it with automatic weights. This way you can adjust it easily. If it matches the character's pose then apply the Armature modifier and clear the parent (Alt+P).

Comment: After this, you should be able to transfer the weights and parent the cloth to the character's armature (with empty groups).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it.